# Convert folder of images to video using WP7+

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dll, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use [Slicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com/releases/view/14364) dll reference to convert images to a video file, but I am having a problem with adding the reference to my Windows Phone project, I get the error

> Reference cannot be added to l because it was not built using the Windows Phone runtime. Windows Phone projects will work only with Windows Phone assemblies.

I searched and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637378/silverlight-class-library-to-windows-phone-7-class-library)  where it's mentioned to

> Create a new class library for Silverlight for Windows Phone 7

I don't know if I am creating the class project right but it's not working I get the same errors as with the win phone project, can't install .dll, does anyone know how I can create the class library correctly without this error?

Or even if it is possible to use Splicer with windows phone 7 & 8?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Splicer isn't built to work on Windows Phone. While it seems like it would make sense that general .NET libraries would work on a .NET compatible platform like WP7 and WP8, that's not necessarily the case. (a little outdated, but here: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/not-every-library-will-work)

You could always check out Splicer from [Codeplex](http://splicer.codeplex.com/), but you'd probably have to do a non-trivial amount of modification to get it to work for your project. I'd surmise you could *maybe* pull it off by just modifying the class libraries in the solution, but there are probably pitfalls included with that. Worse comes to worse, you could take all the source files, copy them into a new Windows Phone library project, and then resolve all the build errors. Either way, it'll involve some work.

Comment: If someone could code a P-frames version of this C#-only mpeg encoder, then we'd be safe. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5834/A-C-MPEG1-Image-Compression-Class